# How do I implement this Objec-C turn based Game Center system in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

I'm following this tutorial and I'm struggling to complete it as nothing is out there on turn based gaming for Swift.

I can successfully get into a match with both users on the same view. I now just need to set up a turn system and allow users to send text input to one another each turn. However, I am completely lost on how to do this as it is done very differently in Objec-C. Any guidance on this would be  much appreciated.

Currently using a Game Center helper from GitHub. Current code:

```
func findGameButton(sender: UIButton) {   // Run the following code when Find Game is hit.

    EasyGameCenter.findMatchWithMinPlayers(2, maxPlayers: 2) // Matchmaking

}


 /**
    Match Recept Data, Delegate Func of Easy Game Center
    */
    func easyGameCenterMatchRecept(match: GKMatch, didReceiveData Data: NSData, fromPlayer playerID: String) {
        print("\n[MultiPlayerActions] Recept Data from Match !")
    }
    /**
    Match End / Error (No NetWork example), Delegate Func of Easy Game Center
    */
    func easyGameCenterMatchEnded() {
        /// When the game finished
        print("\n[MultiPlayerActions] Match Ended !")
    }
    /**
    Match Cancel, Delegate Func of Easy Game Center
    */
    func easyGameCenterMatchCancel() {
        /// if player cancel the game
        print("\n[MultiPlayerActions] Match cancel")
    }
```

This is how the turn based system and sending data is done in Objec-C. How would this be done in Swift? Can it be done better? Would love to see an actual turn based game project written Swift but there are none available.

```
- (IBAction)sendTurn:(id)sender {

    GKTurnBasedMatch *currentMatch = // Set up currentMatch variable by retrieving the match from GameKitHelper singleton, only display one match at a time - keep track of this one match in our currrent match variable.
    [[GameKitHelper sharedInstance] currentMatch];
    NSString *newStoryString;
    if ([inputText.text length] > 250) {
        newStoryString = [inputText.text substringToIndex:249]; // Check if length of string in text is too long. If more than 250 characters we cut it off using the substringToIndex call. If not, we just pass the string into our variable.
    } else {
        newStoryString = inputText.text;
    }
    NSString *sendString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                            mainTextController.text, newStoryString];
    NSData *data = // Created by combining the string thats in mainTextController with the string we just created.
    [sendString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ];
    //cachedOldStory used to rollback in case of failing to send out data
    NSString *cachedOldStory = [mainTextController.text copy];
    mainTextController.text = sendString;

    inputText.text = @"";
    characterCount.text = @"250";
    characterCount.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    NSUInteger currentIndex = [currentMatch.participants // For every turn sent, information about the next person in turn roatation is
                               indexOfObject:currentMatch.currentParticipant];

    GKTurnBasedParticipant *nextParticipant;
    for (int i = 0; i < [currentMatch.participants count]; i++)
    {

    NSUInteger nextIndex = (currentIndex +1 + i) %
                        [currentMatch.participants count];
    nextParticipant = [currentMatch.participants objectAtIndex:nextIndex];
            if (nextParticipant.matchOutcome != GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit) {
            break;
        }
    }

    NSArray *nextParticipants = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:nextParticipant, nil];
    [currentMatch endTurnWithNextParticipants:nextParticipants
                                  turnTimeout:GKExchangeTimeoutDefault
                                    matchData:data
                            completionHandler:^(NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             NSLog(@"%@", error);
           //  statusLabel.text = @"Error, check Network and Game Center. Please try again.";
             mainTextController.text = cachedOldStory;
         }
         else
         {
             // statusLabel.text = @"Your turn is over.";
             inputText.enabled = NO;
         }
     }
     ];

    NSLog(@"Send Turn, %@, %@", data, nextParticipant);

}
```

Comment: So what do you want? Someone should just translate it all for you?

Comment: I don't know if its even possible, its from iOS5. Being able to see any sort of turn based game in Swift would be helpful.